# How can I view a live presentation on multiple devices during a large training session?

Tags: wireless-networking, vnc, video-streaming, presentations, screen-sharing

I'm trying to come up with some presentation solutions for an upcoming large training session.

The presenter wants to setup a local WiFi network and share his presentation to anyone who would like to view it on a device, Laptop, Tablet, Smart Phone. He's expecting anywhere from 200-800 attendees at a time.

I've looked into some screen-sharing software, some VNC options and some video streaming solutions but I'm not sure what would work best in this situation and for the possible volume. We have both Mac and PCs available for the presenter and servers if needed.

Anyone have an idea on what Hardware/Software solutions could work for the network and the presentation?

Answer (score 1):

On the network level multicast should be the most resource efficient solution (provided, the network hierarchy is sufficiently deep.)  Multicast-streaming a screen capture using vlc might be an example.  I've also seen various multicast-based VNC variations.

Comment: A multicast VLC screen capture or VNC setup would appear to work. Though the attendees will have to download a viewer for either multicast option, correct? If so, what about the Tablet and Smart Phone users?

Comment: Good point, this would rule out VNC. But VLC can stream a number of codecs.  If the smart phones are RTP capable, it should work.